# USB-Hub buggy if more than one device connected

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

My USB-Hub is very buggy when more than one device is connected. on a fully updated Ubuntu 23.04. On Windows 11 (dual boot) everything works fine, so a hardware issue can be ruled out. When multiple devices are connected to the  6-port hub, the connection  isn't reliable anymore. Connected bluethooth-devices loose contact for a few seconds each minute and disk-processes like copying stop half-way through.

I currently don't know where to start and sadly cant provide a hub model. But from `lsusb` I know that the USB controller is a `RTS5411`.

`lsubs`:

```
Bus 005 Device 006: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 005 Device 005: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
```

I can't provide any more debug info because I don't know where to start.